# SQL query with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm creating a product filter for e-commerce store. I have a product table, characteristics table and a table in which I store product_id, characteristic_id and a single filter value.

**shop_products** - id, name

**shop_characteristics** - id, values (json)

**shop_values** - product_id, characteristic_id, value

I can build a query to get all the products by a single value like this:

```
SELECT `p`.* FROM `shop_products` `p` 
LEFT JOIN `shop_values` `fv` ON `p`.`id` = `fv`.`product_id` 
WHERE ((`fv`.`characteristic_id`=3) AND (`fv`.`value`='outdoor'))
```

It works fine. Also, I can modify this query and get all the products by multiple values that belong to the very same characteristics group (have identical characteristics_id) like this:

```
SELECT `p`.* FROM `shop_products` `p` 
LEFT JOIN `shop_values` `fv` ON `p`.`id` = `fv`.`product_id` 
WHERE ((`fv`.`characteristic_id`=3) AND (`fv`.`value`='outdoor'))
OR ((`fv`.`characteristic_id`=3) AND (`fv`.`value`='indoor'))
```

but when I try to create a query for multiple conditions with different characteristic_id I get nothing

```
SELECT `p`.* FROM `shop_products` `p` 
LEFT JOIN `shop_values` `fv` ON `p`.`id` = `fv`.`product_id` 
WHERE ((`fv`.`characteristic_id`=3) AND (`fv`.`value`='outdoor'))
AND ((`fv`.`characteristic_id`=5) AND (`fv`.`value`='white'))
```

My guess it does not work because of AND operator that I am using wrong in this case due to there are no records in **shop_values** table that have both characteristic_id 3 and 5.

So my question is how to combine or modify my query to get all related products or maybe it is a flaw to store data like this and I need to create a different kind of **shop_values** table?

Comment: `(`fv`.`characteristic_id`=3) AND (`fv`.`characteristic_id`=5)` always return false
maybe yo mean `((`fv`.`characteristic_id`=3) AND (`fv`.`value`='outdoor')) OR ((`fv`.`characteristic_id`=5) AND (`fv`.`value`='white'))`

Comment: Yes, it will always return false that is my question - how to do it right? I did not mean OR, with OR I will get all the records while I need the records that has both 'outdoor' and 'white'

Comment: What do you want in result? can you put some data and result data?

Comment: Change to OR. Then add `GROUP BY p.id HAVING COUNT (*) = 2`

Comment: If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thank you! Looks like this is what I need.

Comment: Also, note that these are INNER JOINs (which can be demonstrated by executing `EXPLAIN EXTENDED [your query]` immediately followed by `SHOW WARNINGS;`

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation.  You can also use tuples with the `in` clause.  So:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM shop_products p JOIN
     shop_values v
     ON p.id = v.product_id
WHERE (v.characteristic_id, v.value) IN ( (3, 'outdoor'), (5, 'white'))
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT v.characteristic_id) = 2;
```

Notes:

- Unnecessarily escaping column and table aliases (with backticks) just makes the query harder to write and to read.
- In general, using `SELECT p.*` and `GROUP BY p.id` is really, really bad form.  The one exception is when you are grouping by a unique or primary key.  This latter form is actually supported in the ANSI standard.
- A `LEFT JOIN` is not needed.  You need to find matches between the tables for the logic to work.
- The use of `AND` and `OR` is fine for the `WHERE` clause.  MySQL happens to support tuples with `IN`, which somewhat simplifies the logic.